# Table not echoing correctly

Tags: php

I have a table that gets absence days for employees, it was working all fine, however when I tried adding a total row at the end of the table, to get the sum of each column. Everything echoed wrong. What am i doing wrong?

Code:

```
<table>
            <tr> 
                <th>Month</th><th>Nbr Of Weekly Vacations</th><th>Nbr Of Yearly Vacations</th><th>Nbr Of Sick Days</th><th>Holidays</th><th>Marriage Leave</th><th>Motherhood Vacation</th><th>Absense With Reason</th><th>Absense Without Reason</th><th>Annual Leave Remaining</th><th>Deducted Yearly Vacation</th><th>Leave Remaining After Deduct</th>
            </tr>';
             $WeeklyVacationCount = 0;
             $YearlyVacationCount = 0;
             $SickDayCount = 0;
             $HolidayCount = 0;
             $MarriageLeaveCount = 0;
             $MotherhoodVacationCount = 0;
             $AbsenceWithReasonCount = 0;
             $AbsenceWithoutReasonCount = 0;

            for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
                echo '<tr>
                    <th style="text-align:left;">'.date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10)).'</th>
                    <td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'WeeklyVacation').'</td>
                    $WeeklyVacationCount+=$WeeklyVacation;
                    echo "<td>{$WeeklyVacation}</td>"; 
                    <td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'YearlyVacation').'</td>
                    $YearlyVacationCount+=$YearlyVacation;
                    echo "<td>{$YearlyVacation}</td>"; 
                    <td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'SickDay').'</td>
                    $SickDayCount+=$SickDay;
                    echo "<td>{$SickDay}</td>"; 
                    <td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'Holiday').'</td>
                    $HolidayCount+=$Holiday;
                    echo "<td>{$Holiday}</td>"; 
                    <td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'MarriageLeave').'</td>
                    $MarriageLeaveCount+=$MarriageLeave;
                    echo "<td>{$MarriageLeave}</td>"; 
                    <td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'MotherhoodVacation').'</td>
                    $MotherhoodVacationCount+=$MotherhoodVacation;
                    echo "<td>{$MotherhoodVacation}</td>"; 
                    <td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'AbsenceWithReason').'</td>
                    $AbsenceWithReasonCount+=$AbsenceWithReason;
                    echo "<td>{$AbsenceWithReason}</td>"; 
                    <td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'AbsenceWithoutReason').'</td>
                    $AbsenceWithoutReasonCount+=$AbsenceWithoutReason;
                    echo "<td>{$AbsenceWithoutReason}</td>"; 
                    <td>'.(15 - getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'YearlyVacation')).'</td>
                    <td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'DeductedVacation').'</td>
                    <td>'.(15 - getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'YearlyVacation') - getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'DeductedVacation')).'</td>


                </tr>
                ';
            }
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$WeeklyVacationCount</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo       '</table>
```

the way it's echoing:
[image]

Comment: did you tune the acoustics properly?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not using concatenation operator for variable value.

Your Code:

```
echo "<td>$WeeklyVacationCount</td>";
```

Code should be:

```
echo "<td>".$WeeklyVacationCount."</td>";
```

Comment: The op is partially using it. :)

Answer (score 0):

change for loop to this

```
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
            echo '<tr>
                <th style="text-align:left;">'.date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10)).'</th>
                <td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'WeeklyVacation').'</td>';
                $WeeklyVacationCount+=$WeeklyVacation;
                echo "<td>{$WeeklyVacation}</td>"; 
                echo '<td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'YearlyVacation').'</td>';
                $YearlyVacationCount+=$YearlyVacation;
                echo "<td>{$YearlyVacation}</td>";
                echo '<td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'SickDay').'</td>';
                $SickDayCount+=$SickDay;
                echo "<td>{$SickDay}</td>"; 
                echo '<td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'Holiday').'</td>';
                $HolidayCount+=$Holiday;
                echo "<td>{$Holiday}</td>"; 
                echo '<td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'MarriageLeave').'</td>';
                $MarriageLeaveCount+=$MarriageLeave;
                echo "<td>{$MarriageLeave}</td>"; 
                echo '<td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'MotherhoodVacation').'</td>';
                $MotherhoodVacationCount+=$MotherhoodVacation;
                echo "<td>{$MotherhoodVacation}</td>"; 
                echo '<td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'AbsenceWithReason').'</td>';
                $AbsenceWithReasonCount+=$AbsenceWithReason;
                echo "<td>{$AbsenceWithReason}</td>"; 
                echo '<td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'AbsenceWithoutReason').'</td>';
                $AbsenceWithoutReasonCount+=$AbsenceWithoutReason;
                echo "<td>{$AbsenceWithoutReason}</td>"; 
                echo '<td>'.(15 - getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'YearlyVacation')).'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'DeductedVacation').'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.(15 - getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'YearlyVacation') - getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'DeductedVacation')).'</td>';


            echo '</tr>';
        }
```

Comment: i got undefined variables, for $weeklyvacation and all other values i got

Answer (score 0):

Your code is riddled with errors.

```
 echo '<tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;">'.date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10)).'</th>
      <td>'.getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'WeeklyVacation').'</td>
       $WeeklyVacationCount+=$WeeklyVacation;
        echo "<td>{$WeeklyVacation}</td>";
```

It's really a mess

```
 <tr>
     <th style="text-align:left;" >
              <?php echo date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10)); ?>
     </th>
     <td>
              <?php echo getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'WeeklyVacation'); ?>
     </td>
              <?php $WeeklyVacationCount += $WeeklyVacation; ?>
     <td>
              <?php echo $WeeklyVacation; ?>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm not disappointing, you should pick a quoting style and stick with it.  See how much easier it is to read with some formatting.

Comment: When it's that messy, it's neigh impossible to see what is going on.  A majority of it is just missing `.` or `'` or other little things like swapping a `"` for a `'`.  Id suggest looking into a template engine they are not that hard to setup and would save so much headache.  Plus all the cool kids use them.